Cannot rewrite in goal using Equations Package in Coq?
I am using Equations Package in coq , and currently I have this expression in my goal:
evalMS (if_then_else (if_then_else t1_1 t1_2 t1_3) t4 t5)

and this in my context
H: None = evalS (if_then_else t1_1 t1_2 t1_3)

i wnat to evalute the first expression, but I can't figure it out.
first I used simp evalMS. and got
evalMS_unfold_clause_1 (if_then_else t1_1 t1_2 t1_3)
  (inspect (evalS (if_then_else t1_1 t1_2 t1_3))) t4 t5

then when I try rewrite <- H. I get this error
Abstracting over the term "evalS (if_then_else t1_1 t1_2 t1_3)" leads to a term
fun o : option FCPLang =>
evalMS_unfold_clause_1 (if_then_else t1_1 t1_2 t1_3) (inspect o) t4 t5 =
evalBS (if_then_else (if_then_else t1_1 t1_2 t1_3) t4 t5)
which is ill-typed.
Reason is: Illegal application: 
The term "evalMS_unfold_clause_1" of type
 "forall t1 : FCPLang,
  {b : option FCPLang | evalS t1 = b} -> FCPLang -> FCPLang -> option FCPLang"
cannot be applied to the terms
 "if_then_else t1_1 t1_2 t1_3" : "FCPLang"
 "inspect o" : "{b : option FCPLang | o = b}"
 "t4" : "FCPLang"
 "t5" : "FCPLang"
The 2nd term has type "{b : option FCPLang | o = b}" which should be a subtype of
 "{b : option FCPLang | evalS (if_then_else t1_1 t1_2 t1_3) = b}".

Also this my definition of evalMS:
Definition inspect {A} (a : A) : {b | a = b} := exist _ a eq_refl.
Notation "x 'eqn:' p" := (exist _ x p) (only parsing, at level 20).
(*This definition tells Coq we'll prove the well-foundedness wf by showing that
the (measure term) will decrease (lt).*)
Equations? evalMS (term : FCPLang) : (option FCPLang) by wf (measure term) lt :=
evalMS (if_then_else t1 t2 t3) with inspect (evalS t1) => {
| Some (b true) eqn: eq1 => evalMS t2;
| Some (b false) eqn: eq2 => evalMS t3;
| Some (n n0) eqn:eq3 => None;
| Some A' eqn: eq4 => evalMS (if_then_else A' t2 t3);
| _ => None
};
evalMS (n C) := Some (n C);
evalMS (b B) := Some (b B).
- apply PeanoNat.Nat.lt_succ_r. rewrite (PeanoNat.Nat.add_comm (measure t1)). rewrite Arith_prebase.plus_assoc_reverse_stt. apply PeanoNat.Nat.le_add_r.
- apply PeanoNat.Nat.lt_succ_r. rewrite (PeanoNat.Nat.add_comm). apply PeanoNat.Nat.le_add_r.
- destruct t1. * discriminate eq4. * discriminate eq4.
* simpl. apply decreasing_measure in eq4. simpl in eq4. apply Arith_prebase.lt_n_S_stt. apply Arith_prebase.lt_n_S_stt. apply Arith_prebase.lt_S_n in eq4.
rewrite Arith_prebase.plus_assoc_reverse_stt. rewrite (PeanoNat.Nat.add_comm (measure f + measure f0 + measure f1)).
rewrite (Arith_prebase.plus_assoc_reverse_stt (measure t1_1 + measure t1_2 + measure t1_3)). rewrite (PeanoNat.Nat.add_comm (measure t1_1 + measure t1_2 + measure t1_3)).
apply Plus.plus_lt_compat_l_stt. assumption. Qed.


Could you edit your question to provide a MWE that works when copied and pasted so that it can be tried out ? It is very hard (sometimes impossible) to debug without trying it out.
Could you also specify which version of Equations you are using ? Some stuffs like handling of with clause have been improved in Equations 8.20.
Otherwise, all I can see is that it seems like a dependency issue. You are trying to rewrite a variable but another depends on it or sth like that, so I don't think it is an issue with Equations.
You can try to unfold / destruct inspect first to see what is going on.

Are you sure your definition is correct?
Perhaps your program should be like the one below.
It doesn't consider the case if an evaluation leads to
if_then_else (if_then_else t11 t12 t13) t2 t3) because that should not be possible if the computation  of (if_then_else t11 t12 t13) is not stuck.
From Equations Require Import Equations.
From Coq Require Import List Arith Nat Lia.

Definition inspect {A} (a : A) : {b | a = b} := exist _ a eq_refl.
Notation "x 'eqn:' p" := (exist _ x p) (only parsing, at level 20).
(*This definition tells Coq we'll prove the well-foundedness wf by showing that
the (measure term) will decrease (lt).*)

Inductive FCPLang :=
| b (b:bool)
| n (n:nat)
| if_then_else (t1 t2 t3 :FCPLang)
.

Equations measure (f:FCPLang) : nat :=
| if_then_else t1 t2 t3  => 1 +  measure t1 + measure t2 + measure t3
| _ => 0.

Equations evalS (t:FCPLang) : option FCPLang :=
| _ => Some t.

Equations evalMS (term : FCPLang) : (option FCPLang) by wf (measure term) lt :=
evalMS (n C) => Some (n C);
evalMS (b B) => Some (b B);
evalMS (if_then_else (b true) t2 t3) => evalMS t2;
evalMS (if_then_else (b false) t2 t3) => evalMS t3;
evalMS _ => None.

Next Obligation.
rewrite measure_equation_3. lia.
Defined.

Next Obligation.
rewrite measure_equation_3. lia.
Defined.

